# Format price with javascript in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, javascript

In javascript I have calculated a number. Which I want to display as a price.

My JS file

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    function irreleventCalculations() {
        // black magic here
        return 19.949999;
    }
    var price = irrelevenCalculation();

    jQuery('#myCustomPriceDiv').text(formatedPrice);

    return $;
});
```

How should I do this in Magento 2?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: try using `.toFixed(2)` method. Ie `formatedPrice = price.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @R.S I want it to format the price according to the settings. So the correct symbol and some countries have more then two floats

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at [shipping_method/price.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2d82d19010a2deee42ab67e62627b84169f0ab8a/app/code/Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js)

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
    ],
    function ($,quote, priceUtils) {
        "use strict";
            ......
            formatedPrice = getFormattedPrice(price)

            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                //todo add format data
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: That helped. I'll post my code in a seperate answer. But accept yours.

Comment: This is working only on cart and checkout pages. On the other pages window.checkoutConfig is undefined and can't access quote object and throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined
    at quote.js:13`

Comment: @MiroslavPetroff Did you find a simple solution for this? Other than writing own code to get the price format?

Comment: For those looking how to get the actual priceFormat object (depending of the store config): https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/151836/77158

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer of R.S

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function ($, priceUtils) {
    "use strict";

    function irreleventCalculations() {
        // black magic here
        return 19.949999;
    }
    var price = irrelevenCalculation();
    price = priceUtils.formatPrice(price);


    jQuery('#myCustomPriceDiv').text(formatedPrice);

    return $;
});
```

Comment: This seems to work only for non localized price formats.