# Magento2 - How to use Magento_Catalog/js/price-box to format price in template?

Tags: magento2, price, requirejs, format

I want to format my price in template, and I find some place told about `Magento_Catalog/js/price-box`, But I don't know how to use it, Anyone can help me show me how to do.

Comment: have you create custom theme in your magento?

Comment: No need new theme, I just customized a part of cart template.

Comment: Magento_Catalog/js/price-box this is show js file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) `Magento_Catalog/js/price-box` is used for formatting price amount.

```
  function formatPrice(amount, format, isShowSign) {
     ......
  }
```

- `amount`: is price amount (is a number)
- `format` is a Object, having some property: `decimalSymbol`, `groupLength`, `groupSymbol`, `pattern`, `precision`, ... One the checkout page, we can check `window.checkoutConfig.priceFormat`

[image]

- `isShowSign`: is a Boolean value. Will show `+/-` (add/minus) sign to the price.

2) The good example for using the price box js is in One Page Checkout.

One the checkout page, the checkout config is stored in a global Js variable. We can check in Browser Console: `window.checkoutConfig`

[image]

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js`
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/estimation.js`
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/shipping-rates.js`

```
       /**
         * Format shipping price.
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
        },
```

There is a note: `quote.getPriceFormat()` gets the value from `window.checkoutConfig.priceFormat` object.

**[EDIT]** we can use:

```
<script>
        window.orderPriceFormat = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->getPriceFormat($block->getStore()); ?>;
</script>
```