# Magento 2 - Format Price in Product detail page with locale currency symbol

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, price

I need to format my custom price on product detail page.

I've already refer this [KO Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228878/format-price-value-in-knockout-template) and [Using Javascript](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/format-price-with-javascript-in-magento-2) question but both have same solution of using  `quote.getPriceFormat()` for formatting.

But in my case on product detail page quote object is not available so how can I format the price with a local currency symbol.

```
var ko = require('priceUtils');
ko.formatPrice(10,{}); //Price format Object{}
output : "10,00" // expected result $10.00
```

Comment: You need it in your html file?

Comment: Post your code, where you displayed your custom price.

Comment: @aravind Yes in html file.

Comment: @Ranganathan updated the code

Comment: Did you added a component js for the html file?

Comment: everything is working fine just I need to get that price with local currency symbol